# Creating a list of strings when input is not separated python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this name list that i got online,the list is 200 names long,here is a sample of it that i have saved in a text file.

```
John
Noah
William
James
Logan
Benjamin
...
```

I want them to be a *list of strings* i.e

```
x=['John','Noah','William',...]
```

I searched for questions similar but didn't find exactly what i need, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what is the input ? one string ?

Comment: @W-B yes it a text of names,just as in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is a file you can do...

```
x = []
with open('file_name', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       x.append(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [The Pineapple's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385173/creating-a-list-of-strings-when-input-is-not-separated-python/53385217#53385217), you can also do `list comprehension`:

```
with open('file_name', 'r') as f:
    x=[i.rstrip() for i in f]
```

Now:

```
print(x)
```

Is the 200 names in a list.

Comment: it is a text seperated by '\n' inside a notepad(each name is on a line)

Comment: This does not make sense. How can you iterate over `f` ?

Comment: @mad_ Of course you can!, Demo of an answer of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list/48290921#48290921

Comment: @U9-Forward i wish i knew how to accept an answer,i am not seeing the button :)

Answer (score 0):

If data is contained in a file

```
with open('file_name', 'r') as f:
    data=f.readlines() # this will be a list of names
```

OR

```
with open('file_name', 'r') as f:
        data=f.read().splitlines() # to remove the trailing '\n'
```